# Multiple NA's for the last variables of linear regression model in R

Tags: r, variables, regression, linear-regression, na

I am trying to run a linear regression model where I have dummy variables in my data to indicate if a certain predictor variable is not present. I have a total of 15 predictor variables.

No matter the order of my predictor variables, the last five variables always result in `NA`.

This problem is almost exactly the same as the one asked here: [linear regression "NA" estimate just for last coefficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337761/linear-regression-na-estimate-just-for-last-coefficient)

I tried adding -1 or +0 to the code

```
lm(H~id11+id21+id22+id23+id24+id31+id41+id42+id43+id52+id71+id81+id82+id90+id95, data=macro.shed)
```

And that resulted in only one less value being `NA`. So now I have 4, instead of 5, predictor variables being `NA`.

I am reading in my data from csv documents.

This is my code:

`watershed = read.csv("nlcd_2000_watershed.csv")`
`macro_2000 = read.csv("wapp_macro_2000.csv")` 
`temp1 = matrix(watershed$Area,ncol=15,byrow=T)` 
nlcd_watershed = data.frame(cbind(unique(watershed$WaterID),temp1)) names(nlcd_watershed)=c("WaterID",paste("id",unique(watershed$Value),sep="")) 
macro.shed = merge(macro_2000,nlcd_watershed,by.x="WaterID",by.y="WaterID") 
data.frame(unique(watershed$Value),unique(watershed$NLCD))

This is my data for macro.shed:

```
dput(macro.shed)
structure(list(WaterID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L), ID = structure(c(1L, 16L, 
2L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 15L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 14L), .Label = c("L1", 
"L10", "L11", "L12", "L13", "L14", "L15", "L16", "L2", "L3", 
"L4", "L5", "L6", "L7", "L8", "L9"), class = "factor"), Date = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "8/20/2001", class = "factor"), 
    UTMX = c(607308L, 607112L, 598526L, 592235L, 603094L, 597749L, 
    605523L, 608668L, 600517L, 601806L, 597548L, 593815L, 591453L, 
    607187L, 606851L, 589528L), UTMY = c(4639040L, 4643780L, 
    4622470L, 4608350L, 4629780L, 4623340L, 4634330L, 4636950L, 
    4628160L, 4630380L, 4621720L, 4611960L, 4607960L, 4636480L, 
    4636020L, 4605120L), Watershed = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L), .Label = c("Cold Spring Creek", 
    "Drake Brook", "Dutchess County Airport", "East Branch Wappinger", 
    "Great Spring Creek", "Grist Mill Creek", "Hunns Lake Creek", 
    "Little Wappinger", "Upton Lake Creek", "Wappinger Creek", 
    "Wappinger Falls"), class = "factor"), richness = c(37L, 
    20L, 32L, 14L, 23L, 20L, 23L, 28L, 25L, 32L, 31L, 30L, 23L, 
    33L, 19L, 19L), H = c(0.9, 1, 0.9, 0.8, 1, 0.8, 0.7, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.9, 1), EPT = c(18L, 14L, 13L, 3L, 15L, 12L, 
    15L, 19L, 15L, 21L, 17L, 16L, 13L, 20L, 13L, 12L), DOM = c(62.1, 
    61.5, 64.1, 73.7, 53.4, 74, 80.3, 59.2, 55.6, 56.8, 57.4, 
    59.4, 54.2, 59.8, 66, 52.2), PMA = c(58.1, 51, 59.3, 39.9, 
    58.4, 45.2, 54.5, 75.3, 56.2, 64.3, 66, 53.7, 55.6, 60.4, 
    52.3, 42.4), FBI = c(3.8, 3.4, 4, 3.9, 3.6, 4.2, 5.2, 3.8, 
    3.5, 4.1, 3.7, 3.7, 4, 3.8, 3.5, 3.6), BAP = c(8.3, 6.8, 
    7.8, 3.9, 7.4, 6, 6.8, 8.4, 7.5, 8.2, 8.3, 7.8, 6.8, 8.3, 
    6.6, 6), Insects.sample = c(7123L, 516L, 2061L, 1341L, 921L, 
    961L, 580L, 1567L, 1180L, 4226L, 4133L, 1400L, 2325L, 2596L, 
    687L, 609L), id11 = c(216900L, 216900L, 4923900L, 131400L, 
    1806300L, 0L, 41945400L, 250200L, 200700L, 1908000L, 4500L, 
    4500L, 4500L, 4500L, 4500L, 25427700L), id21 = c(83700L, 
    83700L, 1163700L, 1290600L, 0L, 0L, 11841300L, 2824200L, 
    110700L, 136800L, 9000L, 9000L, 9000L, 9000L, 9000L, 9145800L
    ), id22 = c(111600L, 111600L, 596700L, 7245000L, 63900L, 
    11700L, 7293600L, 5060700L, 323100L, 179100L, 55800L, 55800L, 
    55800L, 55800L, 55800L, 3876300L), id23 = c(413100L, 413100L, 
    611100L, 1817100L, 0L, 0L, 11107800L, 208800L, 1713600L, 
    33300L, 204300L, 204300L, 204300L, 204300L, 204300L, 6268500L
    ), id24 = c(239400L, 239400L, 4547700L, 193500L, 26100L, 
    10800L, 48636900L, 88200L, 1139400L, 41400L, 16200L, 16200L, 
    16200L, 16200L, 16200L, 14818500L), id31 = c(63900L, 63900L, 
    14319000L, 526500L, 139500L, 0L, 58785300L, 398700L, 1723500L, 
    73800L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 31161600L), id41 = c(384300L, 
    384300L, 4142700L, 0L, 86400L, 0L, 9641700L, 357300L, 3166200L, 
    392400L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 963900L), id42 = c(729000L, 
    729000L, 508500L, 209700L, 13500L, 0L, 4072500L, 682200L, 
    2137500L, 31500L, 10800L, 10800L, 10800L, 10800L, 10800L, 
    3993300L), id43 = c(1224000L, 1224000L, 1266300L, 1532700L, 
    0L, 418500L, 6607800L, 695700L, 1356300L, 10800L, 78300L, 
    78300L, 78300L, 78300L, 78300L, 5419800L), id52 = c(16200L, 
    16200L, 57600L, 600300L, 17100L, 0L, 1730700L, 958500L, 120600L, 
    101700L, 20700L, 20700L, 20700L, 20700L, 20700L, 0L), id71 = c(22500L, 
    22500L, 780300L, 208800L, 5400L, 0L, 1139400L, 533700L, 7085700L, 
    582300L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 198000L), id81 = c(221400L, 
    221400L, 3398400L, 0L, 1649700L, 0L, 287100L, 155700L, 6300900L, 
    1511100L, 13500L, 13500L, 13500L, 13500L, 13500L, 264600L
    ), id82 = c(665100L, 665100L, 1513800L, 41400L, 447300L, 
    0L, 3083400L, 132300L, 616500L, 53100L, 2943900L, 2943900L, 
    2943900L, 2943900L, 2943900L, 931500L), id90 = c(2142000L, 
    2142000L, 826200L, 215100L, 0L, 17705700L, 630000L, 1156500L, 
    590400L, 15300L, 4598100L, 4598100L, 4598100L, 4598100L, 
    4598100L, 311400L), id95 = c(4628700L, 4628700L, 113400L, 
    4897800L, 0L, 10526400L, 358200L, 2281500L, 1431900L, 33300L, 
    4982400L, 4982400L, 4982400L, 4982400L, 4982400L, 0L)), .Names = c("WaterID", 
"ID", "Date", "UTMX", "UTMY", "Watershed", "richness", "H", "EPT", 
"DOM", "PMA", "FBI", "BAP", "Insects.sample", "id11", "id21", 
"id22", "id23", "id24", "id31", "id41", "id42", "id43", "id52", 
"id71", "id81", "id82", "id90", "id95"), row.names = c(NA, -16L
), class = "data.frame")
```

How do I make it so that the last variables are not resulting in `NA`s?

Comment: Could we get a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), please?

Comment: I edited the question to add my code in, do you also need the raw data?

Comment: `dput()` will help you include some data here.  There's no need to include *all* of it, but enough so that we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: very long amount of data, sorry, I hope this is what you wanted with the dput? I have a few columns so I didn't want to exclude anything that could be important.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm not being clear: to help you, the users of Stackoverflow need the data to reproduce your error.  `dput(macro)` is all we need because your `lm()` statement uses only data from the dataframe called `macro`.  

However, I see that you get `dput(macro) Error in dput(macro) : object 'macro' not found` when you try `dput(macro)`.  

Make it easy for us to help you. We should be able to read in your data and run the code you reproduce to get the same error as you.

Comment: Sorry Steven, I'm new to posting questions here. R was acting up and I restarted it to get the correct information for you.  There should be no more error macro not found in the script. Also, for the LM, data=macro.shed, not just macro, which I amended as well. macro.shed is a combination of the watershed data and macro data by water ID.

Comment: The output from `dput(macro.shed)` is probably all that's needed to reproduce this.

Comment: thanks @pete I changed it to the macro.shed data.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to fit 14 predictors (15 if you include an intercept) with only 16 observations.

That's not enough data to calculate that many parameters, which is why you're only getting estimates for some of them.

You'll need to use some sort of regularisation or model selection, but even then your estimates will be sensitive to the method you choose.

Comment: Thank-you. Do you have any suggestions on how to do that in R?

Comment: That's probably a question for CrossValidated. It's really going to depend on what you're trying to do with your data, although I suspect the answer here is that there's just not enough data to estimate that model.

Answer (score 1):

To add on to the answer provided by @Pete, many of your variables have high collinearity.  To visualize this easily,

```
library(corrplot)

corPlot <- cor( macro.shed[, c(15:29)])

corPlot <- cor(x)
corrplot(corPlot, method = "number")
```

Comment: that corrplot graphic is SO much easier to read than what I've been doing thank-you!!